# Return multiple results using Xpath

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I was hoping if someone could help, I am trying to use an xpath expression  to return the button values indicated in the HTML snippet below. Is it possible to return both values within a single xpath?

```
<div class="selectedFacetsContainer">    
 <div class="selected-facets-slide">
   <button class="facet-button btn-large selected ng-scope keyword-facet" ng-click="removeFacet(sf)" ng-repeat="sf in selectedFacetsList">Thank</button>
   <button class="facet-button btn-large selected ng-scope keyword-facet" ng-click="removeFacet(sf)" ng-repeat="sf in selectedFacetsList">You</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get both elements using a single xpath. Here's how -

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('.facet-button btn-large selected ng-scope keyword-facet'));
```

You can also get them using `className` -

```
driver.findElements(By.className('facet-button btn-large selected ng-scope keyword-facet'));
```

But in order to extract values from each one of them, you need to write some extra code for that.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @Girish Sortur, much appreciated

Comment: @AkifTahir what were you looking for? You want to extract values from them or just an xpath that returns both the elements? Or it solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you are looking for.

```
_driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='selected-facets-slide']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get both values using one Xpath.

```
List<WebElement> abc = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class='facet-button btn-large selected ng-scope keyword-facet']"));
System.out.print(abc.size());
Iterator<WebElement> itr = abc.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext())
{
    WebElement a = itr.next();
    System.out.println(a.getText());
}
```

Actually you have to use `findElements()` which returns a `List` of `WebElement`s. Once we get list of `WebElement`s we can use an `Iterator` to get all values from the `WebElement`.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments you seem to be OK with using a CSS selector instead of an XPath. If so, this code should work. It gets a `List` of `WebElement` that you can then loop through to get the values that you want.

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button.facet-button.btn-large.selected.ng-scope.keyword-facet"));
for (WebElement button : buttons)
{
    System.out.println(button.getText().trim());
}
```